# Admob тестовая реклама показывается в Unity, но не на реальных устройствах

Tags: unity3d, admob

Даже в пустом Unity 2021.2.14f1, проект когда я устанавливаю admob плагин (7.0.0, 6.1.2 or 6.1.0) и добавляю простой рекламмный скрипт, как в прошлые разы. Тестовая реклама показыывается в Unity, но при этом на реальных дейвайсах не отображается,

Как быть?

Код:

```cs
    private BannerView bannerView;


        void Start()
        { 
            MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });  
            RequestBanner();
        }

        private void RequestBanner()
        {
            string adUnitIdBr = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
            this.bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitIdBr, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            this.bannerView.LoadAd(request);
        }
```

Comment: Код 3 приходит?